# AWS cannot find X509 certificate store

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, pnp-core-sdk

I'm currently using PnPCoreAuthenticationX509CertificateOptions as my authentication method. The problem is it runs correctly on my desktop, but when I upload the code to the AWS lambda function, it throws this exception right away. Here is the guide I'm following [PnP Core Auth](https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/using-the-sdk/configuring%20authentication.html)

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'certificate')

or

> The specified X509 certificate store does not exist

Here the sample code to load certificate

```cs
private X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate(string certificateThumbprint)
{
    try
    {
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        var certificateCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certificateThumbprint, false);
        store.Close();

        return certificateCollection.First();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(err.ToString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

My configuration for authentication

```cs
// Add the PnP Core SDK library
services.AddPnPCore(options =>
{
    options.PnPContext.GraphFirst = true;
    options.HttpRequests.UserAgent = "ISV|Contoso|ProductX";

    options.Sites.Add("Default", new PnPCoreSiteOptions
    {
        SiteUrl = siteUrl
    });
});
services.AddPnPCoreAuthentication(
    options =>
    {
        // Configure an Authentication Provider relying on Windows Credential Manager
        options.Credentials.Configurations.Add("x509certificate",
            new PnPCoreAuthenticationCredentialConfigurationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                TenantId = tenantId,
                X509Certificate = new PnPCoreAuthenticationX509CertificateOptions
                {
                    StoreName = StoreName.My,
                    StoreLocation = StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                    Thumbprint = thumbprintCerf
                }
            });

        // Configure the default authentication provider
        options.Credentials.DefaultConfiguration = "x509certificate";

        // Map the site defined in AddPnPCore with the 
        // Authentication Provider configured in this action
        options.Sites.Add("Default",
            new PnPCoreAuthenticationSiteOptions
            {
                AuthenticationProviderName = "x509certificate"
            });
    });
```